# Correlating PHP errors to HTTP requests in GAE php74 standard environment

Tags: php, google-app-engine, logging, gcloud, stackdriver

We used to run a php55 Google App Engine standard environment for our application. With this setup, we would output logs using `syslog`, and both those logs and any PHP errors would be automatically correlated to the HTTP request that caused them, when viewed in Google Cloud Logging.

For example (not our app, but shows the functionality): [image: correlated logs]

However, after upgrading to the php74 standard environment, we lost this correlation for both the logs and the errors. According to the docs, the Cloud Logging library is recommended for the correlated logs, which is fine. But I can't see a way to correlate PHP errors to the HTTP requests.

That is, I'd like to know that Request X went in, then during the processing of Request X a PHP error was triggered. The php55 runtime seemed to do this out-of-the-box, but I have no idea how to do it with the standard php74 runtime. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: For this post, I think screenshots are OK provided that you explain what they are showing. Show an image of your working example and the problem example. Also include details on your app deployment yaml.